# Assigning Function Value Instead of Using Return Keyword, and its Effect on Synchronised Code Execution

Tags: vb.net, synchronization, return

I am wondering if there is a difference between using

```
Public Function Foo() As Double
  Return 3.0
End Function
```

and

```
Public Function Foo() As Double
  Foo = 3.0
End Function
```

but specifically with respect to code execution.

I am attempting to manage a multithreaded application using synchronisation, and am not sure if I am capturing every lock and release correctly.

I understand that code lines after 'Return' are not executed because the function loses focus, but what if the 'Return' is wrapped in a SyncLock block?

```
Public Function Foo() As Double
  SyncLock fooLock 
    Return 3.0
  End SyncLock
End Function
```

Does the End SyncLock get called? Is the SyncLock block shorthand for:

```
Public Function Foo() As Double
  Dim result as Double
  Try
    Threading.Monitor.Enter(fooLock)
    result = 3.0
  Finally
    Threading.Monitor.Exit(fooLock)
  End Try
  Return result
End Function
```

If my understanding is correct then the Finally block comes before the function releases focus, but alternatively if the Finally waits on the Return and subsequent code, then it may be a while before the Finally gets a chance, i.e.

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
  Dim a As Double = Foo
  ...Do other things
End Sub


Public Function Foo() As Double
  Try
    Threading.Monitor.Enter(fooLock)
    Return 3.0
```

...code returned to executes, 'a' is assigned to the return value of Foo, then perhaps all of the other tasks on the thread are done, then

```
  Finally
    Threading.Monitor.Exit(fooLock)
  End Try
End Function
```

In this case my lock may have held for too long. For value types the first code would be acceptible, but for reference types, the first would release the lock then return a reference to the object and the consumer would have non-synced access to the value, the second may or may not work, depending on how much code is executed inbetween the break in the function.

Could anyone help me straighten these concepts out?

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a difference between RETURN 3 and v = 3

Return X terminates the call right there, but it definitely runs through any try catch finally's you might have open.

v = 3 simply sets up the return value as 3, *but does not return*. Execution continues on in the function until the end of function or an exit function.

I'm not 100% sure about the synclock question, but I'd wager than RETURNing out of it would terminate it properly.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the SyncLock block will return correctly and exit the lock also, but if treating the SyncLock as its equivalent explicit code, the question would still be exactly when the effectife 'Finally' block gets called. In the case of my actual code I am using a ReaderWriterLock so need to be concerned with the specifics of how to structure the code, the SyncLock is more of an academic discussion about what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use the "assign function name a value and return" pattern anymore. Its up there with `REM` for some of us.

That said, if you look at the IL generated from code that uses the return vs assign function name you'll see that it is 100% the same.

As for your other question, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t%28VS.80%29.aspx#emarksToggle):

> SyncLock block guarantees release of the lock, no matter how you exit the block

Comment: The initial intent of using that pattern was due to the competing fact that nothing, including Threading.Monitor.Exit() will get executed after a Return statement, when what I am after is a Property whose return value is appropriately locked for reading at the time of use.